# OpenCV2.3 imwrite saves black image

Tags: image, opencv, save

I am trying to save a JPEG image onto the disk using imwrite, seems that I am missing something. I am always getting a black image of around 4KBs. What am I doing wrong here?
Image I see seems fine but once onto the disk, its completely black.

```
std::vector<int> qualityType(1);
qualityType.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
cv::imwrite("Final.jpg",image,qualityType);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works for me on 8bit (1 and 3 channel) images:

```
std::vector<int> qualityType;
qualityType.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
qualityType.push_back(90);
cv::imwrite("Final.jpg",image,qualityType);
```

In your code `qualityType` is initialized incorrectly. Your vector contains 2 values

```
{<some unknown number>, CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY}
```

but should be

```
{CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, <desired quality value>}
```

Comment: Accepted as I missed the quality factor

Answer (score 2):

imwrite prints on a 0 to 255 scale, but your image is in a 0 to 1 scale. To scale up, use this line:

image.convertTo(image, CV_8UC3, 255.0);

Answer (score 0):

I only had to convert it to  16bit image

```
image.convertTo(image,CV_16UC3,255,255);
```

as per document, 8 or 16 bit images can be saved.