# How to extract Numerical gradient matrix from the image matrix in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, extract, gradient, numerical

i am searching a way to get Numerical gradient from the matrix. The same
function is implemented in matlab's default documentation.http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gradient.html but i couldn't find any in opencv.

I want to port this to C++ using opencv.

should i use sobel for horizontal and vertical gradient or any
other function or way to do it???

```
Mat grad_x, grad_y;
Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;

/// Gradient X
Sobel( mat, grad_x, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3);
imshow("xx",grad_x);
convertScaleAbs( grad_x, abs_grad_x );
/// Gradient Y
Sobel( mat, grad_y, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3);
convertScaleAbs( grad_y, abs_grad_y );

/// Total Gradient (approximate)
Mat res;
addWeighted( abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, res );
```

[EDIT]
solution

```
Mat grad_x,abs_grad_x,grad_y,abs_grad_y;
int type=CV_64F ; 
Gradient.setTo(Scalar::all(0));
/// Gradient Y
Sobel( input, grad_x, type, 1, 0, 3);
convertScaleAbs(grad_x,abs_grad_x);
cv::accumulateSquare(abs_grad_x,Gradient);
/// Gradient Y
Sobel(input, grad_y, type, 0, 1, 3);
convertScaleAbs(grad_y,abs_grad_y);
cv::accumulateSquare(abs_grad_y,Gradient);

    imshow("gradient Mag",Gradient);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the gradient calculation [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html#sobel-derivatives) Just like you have said to calculate sobel gradients, the example does so.

Comment: ok i tried this but my image is grayscale and after the addWeighted i get blank picture. for.eg. check the above code i added in the first post

Comment: after the conversion convertScaleAbs i get blank image for Y image but X images ...what could be the reason?

Comment: If you are getting a black picture, first make sure you don't end up mixing float and int storages in OpenCV which is often the case. Resulting in a ALL 0 value for a certain storage, e.g. IPlImage. Now to make sure you calculate the gradient correctly, dump all values to a file and read it in Matlab and plot it. If it appears in Matlab, means you need to scale your results in OpenCV before you can display them and before you can save them to the disk.

Comment: here is link to one confusion I had while saving the image to the disk. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463732/opencv2-3-imwrite-saves-black-image

Comment: Have you tried to follow the sample in the link in my answer? it should work.

Comment: thanks for fast responses actually i was displaying image through imshow , and it works fine till i dont use convertScaleAbs. Thats why when i use addWeighted for total gradient i always get black image on the screen... My image is full black and with some white lines of finger do you think this could be the reason of it? 

Let me show the image [IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/34hchop.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Rescale your data before displaying it. After sobelX and SobelY, what are the values? Ints or floats? Make sure after scale conversions you atleast have the same data types that is either ints or floats. In case of ints. the range is 0 to 255 assuming 8-bit image content. If you have too many values between 0-10, scale up, take it to 255 or divide the image content by max value and scale it one value at a time. This will require some experimentation. Its onyl that your displaying is incorrect. I hope so !

Comment: [gx,gy]=gradient(img);
num=(gx+i*gy).^2; this is the matlab calculation that i am porting in C++ but still unable to get correct result. So above i am using griadient of sobel x and sobel y by discarding the convertScaleAbs  and addweight function.

Comment: Well do one thing. If you have matlab, save all the values from your matrices and read them in matlab and plot them. See if you get anything there. I am sure you will. But Experiment with what I said. Divide by the largest value and scale up a bit. Just add a scalar value to all entries in the matrices. See if that works which it should. If you can compare the matlab output and the openCV output, that would be great but will require some work to do.

Comment: i could not able to display it , it is not displaying as expected result. Can i send you my complete code ? Also if you dont mind if i can ask your name if it is "Wajih ullah baig"?

Comment: @Wolverine, send me the code. Upload it. yes it is. I am wajih ullah baig. Do we know each other?

Comment: sorry for late reply due to weekend here. Actually i know you by your book and i am very glad and happy to know this that your the writer.I hope i will be in touch with you with respect to my work.Okay here is what i am trying to achieve , i have to use "routine is based on a novel, improved hybrid algorithm for core point localization".

Comment: For that i must first create complex filter and then apply on the image and then make them in small overlapping blocks. After that i need to show the orientations of the edges (ridges of finger), i have the matlab code but the conversion is taking too much time so i am searching better ways to do in opencv. I cant use any other algorthim because it is the requirement of my task. The C++ one which i have written is here http://snipt.org/uhmj5 & the matlab code http://snipt.org/uhna5 I am able to create the perfect complex gaussian filter like matlab but on this gradient part i am stucked.

Comment: i tried without using converto i am not able to run this program however i have even tried with the raw grad_x and grad_y variables in the loop and the result output still is not same

Comment: okay figured out myself above is the solution for the sake of others help

Comment: Thanks Wajih for the above help!

Comment: @wolvorinePk - Great if you have figured out the solution, Do Post your answer please. Sorry that I was too busy to responsd. And NO i am not the writer but the technical reviewer of the OpenCV book you have read. Glad i could help :)