# OpenCV imwrite a float image, which conversion to use?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to store a float image in OpenCV. Converting it to a CV8U image as suggested by [@tomriddle_1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961789/opencv-imwrite-saving-black-png) still stores a black png.

```
reference.type() = 5
reference.channels() = 1
reference.depth() = 5
```

How can I convert the image to a 8bit or 16bit so that imwrite can store the image, while maintaining it's float property i.e: the stored image is not "washed out colours" due to conversion/loss of precision!

```
imshow("5t aligned Mean", reference); //Displays the correct image
//reference.convertTo(reference, CV_8U); //Convert image to 8Bit INCORRECT
reference.convertTo(reference, CV_8U, 255.0, 1/255.0); //Correct image
imwrite(subject.c_str(), reference); //Stores a completely black png
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think inplace conversion from 32 bit float to 8 bit uchar will work. You must have a separate `Mat` for `CV_8U` type.

Comment: The fourth parameter of the `convertTo` method is an optional delta added to the scaled values. Why would you add `1/255.0` to the pixel values? Keep it `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to 16bit by multiplying each float pixel by 2^16-1. Floating point images are stored with values between [0,1] which you want to map to the range [0,2^16-1]

opencv will save 16bit uncompressed in PNG and TIFF with the normal imwrite().

(It will also save them as JPEG although I've had less luck finding things that read 16bit jpeg)

Comment: Would I need to go through each pixel in a for loop using reference.col(1) and reference.row(1)? Or is there a more efficient function to do this?

Comment: what if i do not want to normalize the image because the values have special meaning (e.g. some real world unit)

Comment: @vlad_tepesch - then you need a more complex science type data format (FITS, DICOM, HDF), or seprately agree that the data will be multiplied by 100, or 1000 or whatever on loading

Comment: @vlad_tepesch multiplying the image by a value will not normalize it. this worked for me: img_2_save = 255.0 * img_2_save; imwrite(full_img_path.c_str(), img_2_save);

Answer (score 1):

normalize the image before converting between 0 and 255 using CV_NORM_MINMAX