# How to correctly use cv2.imwrite to save an image in openCV with cv2.selectROI

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying out OpenCV's ROI function. With this I am trying to crop out a section of an image that I load. After that I am trying to save the image as well as show it. Showing it is not much of a problem, but saving it is. The image is being stored as a big black rectangle instead of the actual cropped image. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread("/Path/to/Image.jpg")
    img = resize(im, (400,400), mode='reflect') 
    # Select ROI
    r = cv2.selectROI(img)

    # Crop image
    imCrop = img[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]

    # Save first, then Display cropped image
    cv2.imwrite("../../Desktop/Image.jpg", imCrop) # This is where there seems to be a problem
    cv2.imshow("im", imCrop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can some one please help?

Comment: Can you check the contents of `imCrop`. Is it an integer or float (between 0 & 1). Also just to be super sure, can you try specifying the write format as jpeg?

Comment: it was an float between 0 & 1, I made it 0 to 255.

Comment: So did that make it work?

Comment: Can you debug the value of `r = cv2.selectROI(img)`, also attach the output of `cv2.imshow()` ?

Comment: @UG_ Yes, it did. dtype should be set to uint8.

Comment: damn! I wish I had answered that :P.

Comment: @UG_ Haha... Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: this looks similar to this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571874/opencv-imwrite-saving-complete-black-jpeg (although in C++). To debug it you can try and reload the saved image and inspect it to see if the values correspond to what you had saved and if it's not all 0s but numbers between 0 and 1. To help more, we would need the image to help the debugging.

Answer (score 3):

[`cv2.selectROI`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga8daf4730d3adf7035b6de9be4c469af5) returns the `(x,y,w,h)` values of a rectangle similar to `cv2.boundingRect()`. My guess is that the saved black rectangle is due to rounding issues when converting the bounding box coordinates to an `int` type. So just unpack the `(x,y,w,h)` coordinates directly and use Numpy slicing to extract the ROI. Here's a minimum working example to extract and save a ROI:

Input image `->` Program to extract ROI `->` Saved ROI

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
(x,y,w,h) = cv2.selectROI(image)
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow("ROI", ROI)
cv2.imwrite("ROI.png", ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```