# How to get the image torchvision.utils.save_image saves, without reading it back from disk?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

```
from torchvision.utils import save_image

...
save_image(im, f'im_name.png')
```

In my case (standard mnist), using code from [here](https://github.com/L1aoXingyu/pytorch-beginner/blob/master/08-AutoEncoder/Variational_autoencoder.py), `im` is a `Tensor:96`, and `save_image` works.

I want that image in memory to show it in other plots, and I don't want to read it back after saving it, which seems kind of stupid.

Is there a way to separate the functionality of generating the image and of saving it?

---

Edit

clarification:
I want an equivalent to

```
save_image(im, f'im_name.png')
reread = plt.imread(f'im_name.png')
```

without saving the image and reading it back.
I just want the image, and I want to save it later.
the `save_image` function does some work, like stacking multiple images into one, converting the tensor to images of correct sizes and so on. I want only that part without the saving to disk.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the tensor to an image? If so, check `torchvision.transforms.functional.to_pil_image` . Otherwise, could you clarify what you mean by "wanting the image in memory?" or "generating the image" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About 2 weeks later, I stumbled upon the solution by accident.

```
grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(im)
```

`grid` will be the image `save_image` was just saving.

Comment: Did you by chance get into a situation where the save_image() saves an image with wrong colors different from the original image? I have been facing this challenge and could not find a way to solve it. save_image() saves my image with a dimmer color. I  do not want to ask a new question to avoid repetition.

Comment: @Craving_gold Can't tell for sure, but likely you have either replaced RGB with BGR, or have [normalization issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60021899/913098).  Also check data types - You may lose information due to type conversions. Anyway this is not related to this specific question.