# cv2.imwrite Image being saved as black .jpg (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

When I am trying to save an image, the saved image is black. This is the code for saving the image:-

```
sm = pySaliencyMap.pySaliencyMap(frame_width, frame_height)
saliency_map = sm.SMGetSM(frame)

cv2.imshow('Saliency Map', saliency_map)
filename_saliency =  'saliency_map' + str(saliency_num) + '.png'
cv2.imwrite(filename_saliency, saliency_map)
saliency_num += 1
```

The cv2.imshow displays the image correctly. But, cv2.imwrite operation returns a black image. Any help why is this issue occuring and how to resolve it? Appreciate it!

Comment: most likely your datatypes and or scaling. Type needs to be unit8 and values from 0 to 255

Comment: You can use `saliency_map_int= cv2.normalize(src=saliency_map, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)` and then save your image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV imwrite saving complete black jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571874/opencv-imwrite-saving-complete-black-jpeg)

Answer (score 2):

you can save your image :
for Example :

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread ("Example.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imwrite ("New image.png", img)
```

How to read the image in this module is different. There are many ways to read an image in different forms. Like black and white, color and alpha

```
# Open CV's flags :
IMREAD.UNCHANGED #: alpha channel
IMREAD.GRAYSCALE #: black and white
IMREAD.COLOR     #: colored image
```

Answer (score 1):

Used string format python 3.8 or later. I used 3.9.2 on raspberry pi linux. Don't operator.

```
filename_saliency =  'saliency_map' + str(saliency_num) + '.png'
```

to:

```
filename_saliency =  f'{saliency_map} {str(saliency_num)}.png'
```